# How to trigger Couchbase to syn with iOS when document changed from backend

Tags: ios, iphone, node.js, swift, couchbase

I cloned a project from `https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Grocery-Sync-iOS`. And I have created the `grocery-sync` bucket in Couchbase admin. I have added several documents using iPhone simulator, and it worked becuase the documents did appear in the database. But when I try to change the title of a document, the iOS is not updating the new title of the changed document. And I tried to using the provided node.js module to change this document. Below is the node.js code for change specific document's text.

```
var couchbase = require("couchbase");

// Connect to Couchbase Server

var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('127.0.0.1');
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('grocery-sync', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    // Failed to make a connection to the Couchbase cluster.
    throw err;
  }

  bucket.get('-v-bZh-EUrlr0_ev-rqC8br', function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      // Failed to retrieve key
      throw err;
    }

    console.log(doc);

    var doc = result.value;

    // Store a document

    doc.text = "Random beer from Norway";

    bucket.replace('-v-bZh-EUrlr0_ev-rqC8br', doc, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        // Failed to replace key
        throw err;
      }

      console.log(result);

      // Success!
      process.exit(0);
    });
  });
});
```

The node.js code did work, because I can see the changes in the database. But the iOS app is not updating any changes. the `kCBLReplicationChangeNotification` never gets called. I tried to rerun the simulator, the value is still the old value. So how to update changes when you change the exist document and make the iOS update it's new value? It seems the sync feature is only working one-way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want changes to be replicated to Couchbase Lite instances, you have to go through the Sync Gateway. You can't directly write in the associated bucket.

So the recommended way to do this is to use Sync Gateway's [REST API](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/references/sync-gateway/rest-api/document/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

To replicate the data from the client side to the Couchbase backend server that you have, the [Sync Gateway](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/guides/sync-gateway/index.html) is the component that you need to have set up.
Take a look at the Sync Gateway [REST API](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/references/sync-gateway/rest-api/index.html) as it would allow for HTTP access to your remote Couchbase Server database.

Can also take a look at the [Couchbase blog on the Sync Gateway](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/october/couchbase-live-new-york-couchbase-mobile-102---how-to-add-secure-sync-to-your-mobile-applications) for more in depth discussions too.